# Stop wide image from producing horizontal scrollbar

Tags: html, css

On a webpage I have a wide image, which should take up the right 50% of the screen. It appears as I want it to, but it produces an unwanted horizontal scroll bar. I don't want the image to scale down, I want it to remain looking exactly as it does, but to not produce a horizontal scroll bar. How could I do this?

HTML:

```
<div class="image">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.image {
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    background-image: url('Images/banneriPhone.png');
    width:774px;
    height:759px;
}
```

EDIT: I had some suggestions that i remove the overflow option. This didn't work, so i changed the code around (put the image in the html) but this still didn't work. Here's the CSSDesk link:

http://cssdesk.com/mqZpC

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this in your CSS to hide the scrollbar of the CSS class image:

```
.image {
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    background-image: url('Images/banneriPhone.png');
    width:774px;
    height:759px;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    overflow-y:hidden;
}
```

`overflow-x` will hide the horizontal scrollbar

`overflow-y` will hide the vertical scrollbar

---

Edit: Here you can see some example of the overflow property: http://www.brunildo.org/test/Overflowxy2.html

Comment: This hasn't worked. The scrollbar is still there unfortunately.

Comment: Is there a div around this div with a max-width that is bigger then the 774px of the image div?

Comment: I made a prototype with this CSS - In my example there is no scrollbar - do you have any Example where we can see it? (not in CSSdesk because it's only in your Session when u make something in there - also there is sometimes the problem in CSSDesk)

Comment: "overflow-x: hidden" needs to be the style of the parent.
<body style="overflow: hidden">
  <img src="...."/>
</body>

Comment: @Chuan in the original code `.image` was reflecting a `div`. If you indeed place an actual `img` tag into that `div` it will work, if you will use a `div` and a background image it will work too (as in the original post) without a parent div. If, however, you apply the style to an `img` you will need a parent container. correct.

I would recommend `<div class="image_container"><img src=""/></div>` rather than inline style or applying it on the body itself.

Answer (score 1):

To remove the scrollbar on the image, I did the following and it worked. Add the below to your class where the image is on CSS:

```
overflow:hidden;
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply the following css rules on the element:

```
box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
```

And set your margins:

```
margin:0;
```

The paddings can be left intact because of the box-sizing rules (the padding is not included in the width of the image, which is probably set to 100%).